# No brightness setting?

Tags: settings

I am using a Windows Phone 8 made by an indian manufacturer(Micromax Canvas Win W121). Its not a Lumia phone.My phone is running Windows Phone 8.1 update 2. But there is no brightness slider in settings!.There are only four options, Automatic, Low, Medium, High.I don't know why Automatic option is present, as my phone doesn't have an Ambient Light Sensor.Anyway, even at the lowest setting, the brightness is too high for a dark room.Any way to fix this??

Comment: In Windows Phone, there has never been a brightness slider. Just the three options that you mentioned above. Even now, in Windows 10 Mobile, there is no brightness slider. And in such situation, turn on the 'Automatic' option for brightness as it will detect the surrounding (light or dark), and adjust the brightness according to it.

Comment: I thought 8.1 update added the slider:

Comment: http://www.google.co.in/search?q=brightness+slider+windows+phone&safe=active&tbm=isch&oq=brightness+slider+windows+phone&gs_l=mobile-heirloom-serp.12...19779.25154.0.27009.19.17.2.0.0.1.527.3658.5j4j2j3j1j2.17.0....0...1c.1.34.mobile-heirloom-serp..16.3.551.SRSZ_fBBz3o#mhpiv=2

Comment: That is just color profile (like cool or warm), see here: https://blogs.windows.com/devices/2013/08/07/whats-your-colour-profile/